# Rudin's polynomial notation

Tags: real-analysis

I just want to be sure that I understand Rudin's notation. He writes a monomial as
$$x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \cdots x_k^{n_k},$$
where $n_1, \ldots, N_k$ are non-negative integers. A polynomial $P$ is then a sum of monomials,
$$P(x) = \sum c_{n_1 \cdots n_k} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \cdots x_k^{n_k}$$
where $P$ takes an input in $\mathbb{R}^k$, $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_k)$, the coefficients $c_{n_1 \cdots n_k}$ are allowed to be complex, and there must be finitely many terms.

My question is: what exactly is he summing over, and what does the $c_{n_1 \cdots n_k}$ mean? My best guess is $P(x)$ is defined as "a finite sum over monomials," and each polynomial comes with exponents $n_1, \ldots, n_k$, so $c_{n_1 \cdots n_k}$ is the coefficient of that specific monomial term.

Is this correct? This is not how I would typically write a polynomial, so I just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Btw., how would you write polynomials in many variables?

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, it didn't dawn on me that this is a polynomial in many variables. The only notation I've ever seen is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i x^i$.